# NSDistantObject Protocol for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, network-programming

I've been reading through the docs on how the NSDistantObject class and I can see that it is more or less a binary protocol for sending objects from one NSPort to another. What I'm curious about is the possibility of using this in an iPhone application to share data. Is it possible to have two applications talking to each other on distinct phones using this protocol if the connection is established by a server, or even if its not? (I'm sort of thinking of torrents) Also, how does this interchange format compare to typical data serialization methods such as JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently possible as NSDistantObject is only available for the OS X Foundation framework.
[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/WhatIsCocoa/WhatIsCocoa.html).